# How to cast a GroupedEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I am playing about with the IQueryProvider.Execute command and am passing in an expression which is part of my expression tree project. This command gives me back an object which can be either an OrderedEnumerable or a GroupedEnumerable depending on the original expression. A GroupBy expression creates the GroupedEnumerable object. The following code also creates a GroupedEnumerable object which will show you an example of the problem I am having.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 7, 16, 23, 41, 66 };
object grouped = numbers.GroupBy(n => n % 2 == 0);
```

When “grouped” is an object (of GroupedEnumerable) I cannot cast it to any other type that will allow me to call “GetEnumerator” on it. I am also unable to cast it to anything that will allow me to use it with a “foreach” command for example. If I change the code to use a “var” (as shown below), grouped is now of type OrderedEnumerable. I can get the enumerator and use it in a foreach command.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 7, 16, 23, 41, 66 };
var grouped = numbers.GroupBy(n => n % 2 == 0);
```

Going back to my expression tree project, the IQueryProvider.Execute command returns an object but I need to be able to cast the object to an OrderedEnumerable when the object is a GroupedEnumerable. All the casts I have tried show an error along the lines of “Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`3 to type .....”. Anyone able to tell me how to cast the object to something more useful?

Comment: Please demonstrate your attempt to cast and the exact resulting error.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you want just the even numbers, you should use Where(), not GroupBy().

Comment: The code example is just an example of how to get a GroupedEnumerable. You will see from my question that I am using the IQueryProvider.Execute method that returns an object which is actually of type GroupedEnumerable. My problem is with casting this and nothing to do with even numbers.

Comment: Then you should provide a code example that reflects what you're doing. The above example produces an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<bool, int>>`, not a `GroupedEnumerable` object.

Comment: OK, I’ve tried a few things and I’ve realised that the output from my IQueryProvider.Execute command is actually an object of type “GroupedEnumerable<MyEntityItem,int?,MyEntityItem>”, most defiantly a GroupedEnumerable this time. I’d been playing about with code so I thought my example was giving an example of a GroupedEnumerable. The problem I have, is that I cannot cast to GroupedEnumerable as it’s an internal class and not exposed (as far as I can tell). Is there any way to cast the object back to this type so I can work on it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result of your `GroupBy` call will be `IEnumerable<IGrouping<bool, int>>`. You can see this if you hover over the word `var` in your second code example. Cast it to this type and it will work correctly.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 7, 16, 23, 41, 66 };
object grouped = numbers.GroupBy(n => n % 2 == 0);

IEnumerable<IGrouping<bool, int>> foo = 
    (IEnumerable<IGrouping<bool, int>>)grouped;
```

**Edit**

After your comments above, if the output of your call is `GroupedEnumerable<MyEntityItem,int?,MyEntityItem>`, then you can cast it to `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int?, MyEntityItem>>`.

Comment: When I try to cast in this way it won't compile as it gives the error "IEnumerable<T> requires 1 type argument.

Comment: @Retrocoder: Sorry, I've edited the answer. Give that a shot.

Comment: Hi, that worked fine, so I now have the object cast to a GroupedEnumerable<MyEntityItem,int?,MyEntityItem> which is what I wanted, many thanks for that. You may be able to help me with a second question. This code is in the “IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()” method of a class that derives from IOrderedQueryable<T>. I find that I can’t return the Enumerator of the “GroupedEnumerable<MyEntityItem,int?,MyEntityItem>” as the cast throws an error.

Comment: The error is:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable`3[MyEntityItem,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],MyEntityItem]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyEntityItem]'.

Is it possible to do a cast or is this never going to work?

Answer (score 2):

Just cast the object to `IEnumerable<T>`. The enumerable implementation shouldn't matter to you.